Why does the model lose quality when I bake its texture?
I want to bake a texture for exporting a model, it consists of: 2 diff, mix shader. When baking, the texture loses quality and is completely made up of pixels. How can this be fixed?

baked texture


You need to create an image with a resolution high enough to contain the data you want.
If you create a 1024 x 1024 image, you will have low res (pixelated)
If you create a 2048 x 2048, you will have better results.
If you create a 4k (4096 x 4096), even better.
Find the size that is enough for your needs and not too much for being a huge file.
A good size would be the same as the original image you used in the procedure (it's possible to see that the procedural result is also pixelated, just in a higher resolution).
